# How to make two django projects share the same database

Tags: python, django

I need to make two separate Django projects share the same database. In `project_1` I have models creating objects that I need to use in `project_2` (mostly images).

The tree structure of `project_1_2` is:

```
project_1/
    manage.py
    settings.py
    project_1_app1/
      ...
    ...

project_2/
    manage.py
    settings.py
    project_2_app1/
      ...
    ...
```

Which is the best approach?

**EDIT**: I'm using sqlite3 in my development environment.

I'd like to keep my two django projects as stand-alone projects (so that both can be upgraded safely from their respective repositories).

```
# in project_1/settings.py
import os

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
..

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'development.db'),
    },
}
...
# in project_2/settings.py
import os

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
..

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'development.db'),
    },
}
...
```

In this way, each project has its own `development.db` (the one that I need to be shared):

```
project_1/development.db 
project_2/development.db
```

but I guess I need to do something more to make it shared (and unique).
The best for me would be to keep the `development.db` at *project_1/ path* and thus set the *project_2/settings.py* `DATABASES` to point to *project_1/development.db*.

Comment: whether these projects have common functionality or apps?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/

Comment: look at [boilerplate project](https://github.com/devxplorer/django-multi-instances) i created special for you ;) I reccomend you to use this approach, because most likely you will have shared apps beetween projects.

Comment: thank you for your comments. The 2 projects do not share functionalities or apps, I'd need to keep them as stand-alone projects that are just sharing the database. I explained better my needs in a EDIT.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can simply define the same database in `DATABASES` in your settings.py. So, if your database is PostgreSQL, you could do something like this:

```
# in project_1/settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'common_db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'project_1_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'strong_password_1'
    },
}

# in project_2/settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'NAME': 'common_db',
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'project_2_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'strong_password_2'
    },
}
```

Note that both database users (`project_1_user` and `project_2_user`) should have the appropriate privileges on the database you wish to use. Or you could instead use the same user for both projects.

If you want to have more than just one database per project, you should take a look at the [docs for multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/multi-db/).

On another matter, since you share data, I guess you share functionalities as well. So for example, if `project_1_app1` and `project_2_app1` do same (or similar) things, it seems they could instead be a single [reusable app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/reusable-apps/).

**Edit**

Since you use sqlite3, you should ensure the path you use is the same. So, assuming that `project_1` and `project_2` are siblings, like so:

```
projects
  project_1
    settings.py
    ...
  project_2
    settings.py
    ...
```

you should try this:

```
# project_1/settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'development.db'),
    },
}


# project_2/settings.py

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(
            os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(PROJECT_ROOT)),
            'project_1',
            'development.db'
        ),
    },
}
```

This would give the structure you ask for. Note however that the projects are not both "standalone". `project_2` is clearly dependent on `project_1`'s database.

In any case, perhaps, you should also take a look at the [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html) module for more info.

Comment: Thank you @alxs . I edited my question to explain better my needs. Could you help me with setting the db to the same path?

Comment: @user123892 I updated the answer with the extra info you requested

Comment: I am getting django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation django_migrations when I try to migrate the second app with a different user and SUPERUSER privileges

Comment: @alxs How to manage the migrations for the common database. For eg I had few migrations in projects_1, will I have to manually copy the model changes in the projects_2 and run the migrations? Is there a better way?

Comment: @HenryLynx I guess you have solved this already, but just for the record, this has nothing to do with django and is a lack of permissions for your db user/role. Therefore I would suggest getting to your db's shell to check your role's permissions. Note also, that an OS superuser *may not* have superuser privileges on your db.

Comment: @nimeshkiranverma From what I understand you have two different copies of an app in each of your projects. Instead, you should try to have both projects use a single app which "lives" in a common directory that both projects can access (like a virtualenv). Just like I mentioned in the answer above, you should check the docs about [reusable apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/intro/reusable-apps/).

Comment: @alxs , My use case is to make users of project 1 to be linked to project 2. Both the projects should use the same user base. Can you suggest the best approach ?. My project 1 is a blogging app and project 2 is a e-commerce project. Some functionalities need to be shared too. Best approaches for both?

Comment: @Earthling, there are many ways to address this. For example check my comment above yours. This would ensure similar db structure and at least some common functionalities. Project specific models (such as a UserProfile) can simply have a foreign key to the User model of the common app. Perhaps you should check [multiple databases](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/multi-db/). In any case make sure you understand how migrations are handled between your projects. However, the easiest way would be to have a single project instead of two, at two different paths or (sub) domains.

Comment: @Earthling, I can neither be sure on the specifics of your project(s), nor is there a single solution to this sort of things, so as to make any further suggestions. However, since you have done half the merge already, I would **strongly** suggest to consider having a single project instead of two. It would seriously simplify your setup and help you avoid pitfalls.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to declare in your model in class meta the attribute db_table with a name diferent the name of app + model (Which are automatically generated by Django) the twice projects need the same models. before the run makemigrations and migrate.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'MyModel'
```

Comment: pertinent remembrance

Comment: I am still a little bit confused. So if two projects have accidentally the same model class name you could avoid this (if I understand you correctly) by specifying db_table. But if you use a standard library like auth you have a problem, correct?