# Install django-CMS 3.0 with django 1.6

Tags: python, django, django-cms

Recently I installed `django-CMS` following [this](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/introduction/install.html) tutorial.

While on iOS the `django-cms` installer asks which `django versio`n you need (among other [options](http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/introduction/install.html#use-the-django-cms-installer)), in `Ubuntu 14.04` I do not get to choose and I end-up with `django-CMS 3.3` and `django 1.8`.

I need to use `django-CMS` under `django 1.6`.

I already tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questionspip%20install%20pillow/20925529/how-to-install-django-cms-3-on-django-1-6) but when I run `pip install djangocms-text-ckeditor` `Django 1.6` is uninstalled and the `1.9` version gets installed.

How can I get back the options during the `django-CMS` installation?

Comment: You should explain why you think you need to install an old and unsupported version of Django.

Comment: Hi Daniel, I need django 1.6 because I'm working on a project where django-CMS shall share the database with a django project based on django 1.6. Here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39890835/how-to-solve-table-auth-permission-already-exists-error-when-the-database-is) you find the prequel :-) thank you!

Comment: Did you specify the version of Django-CMS to install when you installed via PIP? If not, then it's possible the latest version is grabbed, which may have a dependency on a later version of Django. Try specifying the appropriate version of django-CMS to pip.

Comment: @Gator_Python: thank you for your input. I did `pip install django==1.6 && pip install django-cms==3.0.9`. Django-cms is successfully installed! .. my problem now is that django-cms is installed as a lib in my virtual env `.dj_cms/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cms` but I need to use it as a django project, with the familiar layout with `settings.py, manage.py, urls.py, ..`. I'm sorry in advance if my comment results naive but I should start to learn somewhere

Comment: Hello @user123892, I don't recommend using the installer for versions under 3.2 as these are no longer supported. I suggest installing djangoCMS 3.0.18 manually (not 3.0.9). Make sure to look at the compatibility table in the djangocms-text-ckeditor README to know which one to install.