# Referencing multiple Django projects from a single monorepo

Tags: python, django

I want to be able to write shared functions that can be accessed in one-off batch scripts and also by the running Django service (to use the ORM)

Currently, I have this in the _init__.py under the my_proj module.

```
if 'DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE' not in os.environ:
    os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'my_proj.blah.blah.settings'
    import django
    django.setup()
```

This works fine for one django project. However, now I want to do reference the ORM functions from another django project, "other_proj" **in the same repo from an independent script that lives outside both django projects**.

Is there a way to "django.setup()" multiple projects at once?

Or, at least, a way to easily toggle the setup between the two projects?

Or is there a better way altogether? (I realize I could create a client library to hit the services while they are running, but would prefer to remove that overhead)

Answer (score 2):

If you want a Django project to access functionality that resides in a different Django project, a client library is an option (as you noted). You could also consider packaging those sets of functionality as re-usable [Django apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/) that you import into each project, or you could abstract them further into re-usable Python modules which get imported into each project. If you're hoping to use the Django ORM from one Project to access data from a different project, then you might be looking for this SO question: [How to make two django projects share the same database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774580/how-to-make-two-django-projects-share-the-same-database/39781404)

I think with more specifics in your question (such as, for example, function X in Project A you wish you could call from Project B) we might be able to be more specific with guidance.

Comment: The apps and databases in each django project are completely orthogonal, live in the same repo, and have separate DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE paths. Does this make it more clear?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I quite understand the case you're trying to implement here; two things that sound maybe-sort-of like what you're asking for are:

1) Running Django projects under [uWSGI in Emperor mode](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Emperor.html) allows you to serve multiple Django projects from one server simultaneously.

2) Django can be configured to run the same project under multiple domains simultaneously using the [Sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/sites/).

I agree, though, that more detail about what you have and what you're trying to accomplish with it is probably necessary to give a satisfying answer.