# What are the problems of having two Django projects sharing the same database?

Tags: python, django, django-migrations

I am building a system that has two components, one is a Web application powered by Django 2.2 and other is a worker that does background processing (its work is not started by the Web app). Both components need to communicate to each other in a bi-directional way.
They will use the same database (there is no need to make them independent), inclusive handling the same tables. From Django the Worker will use only the ORM modules, it will own some tables that are not known by the Web app (and vice versa). So I will **need to run migrations in both components that targets the same database**.

Are there migration problems? or for Django that components are seem as two [Django apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#projects-and-applications) that use the same database?

Comment: Have a look at `select_for_update()`, Basic idea is to lock the database while working with it

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed That will be needed to touch shared tables. But my doubt is about the support for sharing the dabatase, because Django stores metadata about a project in the database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774580/how-to-make-two-django-projects-share-the-same-database

Comment: @AhmedI.Elsayed I checked which tables Django creates. Conflicts may happen if the first migration touches a table that already exists. I can use the models metadata to set table names and avoid those names collision. But the 'django_migrations' table is still shared, but I think problems can be avoided by making sure that app labels are unique across both componentes, since django prefixes that app label in the table name.