# Can two Django projects share the same database?

Tags: python, django, database, azure-web-app-service

I have been learning to deploy databases and Django apps on Azure, and I have several projects on there up and running. My question is, can multiple Django apps share a database? As in the apps are unrelated and will not be sharing information, I just don't want to spin up a new database for each project when realistically I will likely be the only one using it. Is this possible without overwriting other tables in the database?

Comment: check this answer if it helps you [How to make two django projects share the same database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774580/how-to-make-two-django-projects-share-the-same-database#:~:text=You%20just%20need%20to%20declare,projects%20need%20the%20same%20models.)

Answer (score -1):

Example:
Create one project in c:\users\project1
and create one project in c:\users\project2
and go to project2 and go to settings.py and change database variable path

```
DATABASES ={
    'defult':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME' : 'C:\users\project1\db.sqlite3'
}
```

and after project2 use project1 database

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. Wont that overwrite all the auth, migrations, etc tables in that database? I want to run two separate apps concurrently on one database with separate tables.

Comment: For what you want change more variable in settings.py