# Is there a way to share a common table of database between two django projects without faking it?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models, database-design

I am trying to use a same table across two different projects and want to reflect the changes between them.

Let's assume that there is a student table in the data created by PROJECT1-APP1 of django. I want that same student table to use in PROJECT2-APP1. I have searched the interned and get recommendation to import the model from 1 project to other but according to my understanding it is just "faking" it and some functionality like BigAutoFeild and Foreign Keys would not work in this solution. Is there a way that I can use the same database in two different projects which will not mess up with the core operation?

EDIT:
the other questions just shows how to connect database which I know, the problem occurs when I try to use the same tables.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make two django projects share the same database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774580/how-to-make-two-django-projects-share-the-same-database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to create a model in the other app and explicitly specify the database table in the `class Meta` section. Similar to below:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=70)

    class Meta:
       db_table = 'table_persons'
```