# Two django projects with common userbase , authentication and sharing of key functionalities

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-3.2

I'm building a Django v3.2 project that requires merging of 2 projects(social app and ecommerce) - both of which are separate open source django projects. The end goal is to share users, posts and a common user registration and authentication process and keep a common database for both. Project 1 has a 5 docker containers(api backend, worker,scheduler, sql db, redis db) and project 2 has 1 docker container(that has a frontend sandbox ecommerce website). I came across this post while searching which is similar :

[How to make two django projects share the same database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774580/how-to-make-two-django-projects-share-the-same-database)

Based on the post share above, My core question is :

While I'm using 2 separate projects that run their own docker containers, what changes will I have to make so that

> 1. Registration, Authentication & Users are common
> 2. Functionalities are shared.
>    Essentially, I would like to import modules from project1-->project2 and project2-->project1 and design additional functionalities as per need.

I initially tried copying files from project 2 into project 1 so that the project1 social app and functionality is just extended. But I'm running into all sorts of problems. Here is the question pertaining to the same :

[Python3.10:ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'commerce'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74653906/python3-10modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-commerce)